# Calling several times a single test - Google Tests

Tags: c++, testing, googletest, random-testing

I am trying to perform a little of random testing in a piece of software I am developing.
I have a fixture that is initialized with random values, therefore, each test will have different input.

Moreover, what I want is to run one of those test several times(I expect the fixture to be initialized randomly for each execution), is it possible in Google Tests? I need that to be in the code, not to use a argument or something like that.

I am looking for something like `invocationCount` in JUnit.

Comment: HTH: http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/V1_6_AdvancedGuide#Value_Parameterized_Tests

Comment: @PiotrNycz: thanks, I think it can be achievable through 'Value-Parameterized Tests' But I would have to create a specific fixture for the test I want to be repeated.isn't it? Doesn't seems it quite complex just to make a test be repeated?

Comment: I do not have so much experience in GT to answer your question. I agree it seems complex - maybe you can ask google folks directly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about something like this, using an unused [parameter](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#user-content-value-parameterized-tests) and Range()

```
class Fixture : public ::testing::TestWithParam<int> {
    //Random initialisation
};

TEST_P(Fixture, Test1){}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(Instantiation, Fixture, ::testing::Range(1, 11));
```

`Test1` wil be called 10 times (the range end, 11, isn't included), with a new fixture created each time.

Comment: that is what I was discussing with @PiotrNycz at question comments and seems the only available solution. thanks